# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RAND_LIMIT' while running Box2d with OpenAI gym

Tags: python, python-2.7, box2d, openai-gym

I have installed box2d using pip install but when I run OpenAI gym environment for box2d games with python. In my case I am trying to run LunarLander environment:-

```
 import gym
 env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2")
 env.reset()
```

I get this error:

```
[2018-01-02 01:37:39,026] Making new env: LunarLander-v2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ens.py", line 13, in <module>env = gym.make(a)
File "/home/yograj/gym/gym/envs/registration.py", line 164, in make 
return registry.make(id)
File "/home/yograj/gym/gym/envs/registration.py", line 122, in make 
env = spec.make()
File "/home/yograj/gym/gym/envs/registration.py", line 88, in make cls 
= load(self._entry_point)
File "/home/yograj/gym/gym/envs/registration.py", line 17, in load 
result = entry_point.load(False)
File "/home/yograj/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-
27.2.0-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2258, in load
File "/home/yograj/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-
27.2.0-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2264, in resolve
File "/home/yograj/gym/gym/envs/box2d/__init__.py", line 1, in 
<module>from gym.envs.box2d.lunar_lander import LunarLander
File "/home/yograj/gym/gym/envs/box2d/lunar_lander.py", line 4, in 
<module> import Box2D File "/home/yograj/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site 
packages/Box2D/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>from .Box2D import *
File 
"/home/yograj/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/Box2D/Box2D.py", 
line 434, in <module> RAND_LIMIT = _Box2D.RAND_LIMIT
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RAND_LIMIT'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module '\_Box2D' has no attribute 'RAND\_LIMIT\_swigconstant'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037674/attributeerror-module-box2d-has-no-attribute-rand-limit-swigconstant)